# "weird" variable initialization

Tags: c++, variables, initialization

What is meant by:

```
GLuint bindingPoint = 1, buffer, blockIndex;
```

I found this in one tutorial which I need, and I have never seen such a variable initialization before.

Does this line mean

```
GLuint bindingPoint = 1;
GLuint bindingPoint = buffer;
GLuint bindingPoint = blockIndex;
```

?

Comment: [*init-declarator-list*](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/declarations#Simple_declaration)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The line `GLuint bindingPoint = 1, buffer, blockIndex;` is equivalent to the following three:

```
GLuint bindingPoint = 1;
GLuint buffer;
GLuint blockIndex;
```

Both versions define the variables `bindingPoint, buffer, blockIndex`. With `bindingPoint` initialized to `1`.

Comment: The other option (which would only be legal if `buffer` and `blockIndex` had been declared already) would be `GLuint bindingPoint = (1, buffer, blockIndex);`  which would mean "evaluate `1` and throw the result away, evaluate `buffer` and throw the result away, evaluate `blockIndex` and use it to initialize a new variable `bindingPoint` of type `GLuint.

Comment: To be clear: that is not an alternative reading of the original statement.  The statement unambigiously means what StoryTeller has written.  It is what a similar looking statement would mean.